# Detect if script-demand is requested from html-site or url-line

Tags: javascript, php

Samy Kamkar's website, http://samy.pl, offers different versions of load.js.
If you load the script by url (https://samy.pl/load.js) you will get the script containing the following:

```
No source for you! Easter egg #9
```

loading the script via samys side http://samy.pl (look at console) you will get:

```
No source for you! Easter egg #2 ... (and something obfuscated)
```

PS: to get the right script you have to undock your console.

How is he doing this? Is there any possibillity in php to detect the request?

Comment: _"How is he doing this?"_ - SO is the wrong place to ask this since we would just be guessing. _"Is there any possibillity in php to detect the request?"_ - Yes, there is.

Comment: Hi Magnus. Great that there is a way to achive it. Do you have some more info`s?

Comment: Checking the request is pretty basic stuff and is covered in a lot of tutorials. You can, for example, check the `$_SERVER`-super global to get details about the request. If you want more specific info, you need to edit your question to ask a more specific question. What are you looking for? Have you done any research?

Comment: For me all $_SERVER-globals do not differ between calling a file in browser-url or from a html-file. Any hint?